# Facing MicrometerClock issue with spring boot version 2.5.5

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am having Spring Boot version 2.5.5 in my project. I am getting below error while running the project. I think , I'm having some version issue with Spring Boot. I also try to upgrade the version of Spring Boot, but its not working.

Please find my `pom.xml` below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>zodiac.zdc.microservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>zdc-microservice-event-dispatcher</artifactId>
    <version>115.0.0.0</version>
    <name>zdc-microservice-event-dispatcher</name>
    <description>Event dispatcher microservice project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <zara.zerba.version>91.0.0.0</zara.zerba.version>
        <zara.foundation.version>63.0.0.0</zara.foundation.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-atlas</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
      <artifactId>simpleclient</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
      <artifactId>simpleclient_hotspot</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
      <artifactId>simpleclient_servlet</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>resilience4j-spring</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>resilience4j-micrometer</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
      <artifactId>javers-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am facing below exception while running project:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Error processing condition on io.micrometer.spring.autoconfigure.MetricsAutoConfiguration.micrometerClock
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]`
```

Please help me with above issue.

Comment: One first thought: You are using Spring Boot parent in version `2.5.5`, but the other Spring Boot dependencies mentioned are `2.2.6.RELEASE`. I don't know if that's the root cause for your problem, but it's an inconsistency anyway.

Comment: The other versions are all over the place too (micrometer, prometheus, etc.), please first fix your dependencies than edit the question.
Btw most of the version you use here are not supported anymore, you need to upgrade to the latest Boot 3.x: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support

Comment: Also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78105479/micrometer-issue-with-2-5-5-spring-boot-version