# Micrometer Issue with 2.5.5 spring boot version

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, micrometer

I am having spring boot version 2.5.5 in my project. i am getting below error while running the project. i think am having some version issue with spring boot. i also try to upgrade version of spring boot but its not working.

Please below find my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>zodiac.zdc.microservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>zdc-microservice-event-dispatcher</artifactId>
    <version>115.0.0.0</version>
    <name>zdc-microservice-event-dispatcher</name>
    <description>Event dispatcher microservice project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <zara.zerba.version>91.0.0.0</zara.zerba.version>
        <zara.foundation.version>63.0.0.0</zara.foundation.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-atlas</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.0</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
      <artifactId>simpleclient</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
      <artifactId>simpleclient_hotspot</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
      <artifactId>simpleclient_servlet</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>resilience4j-spring</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>resilience4j-micrometer</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
      <artifactId>javers-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am facing below exception while running project.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on io.micrometer.spring.autoconfigure.MetricsAutoConfiguration.micrometerClock     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
```

Please help me with above issue.

Comment: Stop mixing versions. You are mixing incompatible spring boot versions, 2.5.5 and 2.26. Remove the version information from the Spring Boot starters you are using. You are also mixing Micrometer 1.11 and 1.6, don't mix versions of modules of a framework. O and don't post [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78105467/facing-micrometerclock-issue-with-spring-boot-version-2-5-5) of your question with a different user!